# Переделка Js анимации

Tags: javascript, css-animation

Подскажите как изменить код, что бы реализовать анимацию, так, что б через каждые 5 сек происходила анимация данный(mainpage__top__caption,mainpage__top--line-1 и т.д.) На данный момент это все работает когда есть видео, и при окончании ролика оно запускает след ролик и след тексты, как реализовать без видео? Слышал за функцию setTimeout, но не знаю как её сдесь реализовать и нужна ли она тут вообще... 
Вот сам код, JS

```js
function init_video_carousel() {
  var cont = $('.js-video_background');
  var playlist = $('.js-video_background-playlist');
  var playlistItems = $('li', playlist);
  var player = $('.js-video_background-player');
  var video = player.get(0);

  if (!cont.length) {
    return;
  }

  play_video(0);

  // Включаем следующее видео при окончании ролика
  video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    play_video((player.data('currentVideo')) + 1);
  });

  function play_video(index) {
    var min = 0,
      max = playlistItems.length;

    if (index < min) {
      index = max;
    } else if (index >= max) {
      index = min;
    }

    var active = playlistItems.eq(index);
    var activeClass = 'active';

    playlistItems.removeClass(activeClass);
    active.addClass(activeClass);

    player.data('currentVideo', index);

    player.fadeOut('fast', function() {
      if (active.data('src')) {
        video.src = active.data('src');
      }

      if (active.data('poster')) {
        video.poster = active.data('poster');
      }
      video.load();
      $('.mainpage__top').addClass('changing');

      $('.mainpage__top__caption,.mainpage__top__line,.mainpage__top__description').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('.mainpage__top__caption').text(active.data('caption'));
        $('.mainpage__top--line-1').text(active.data('line-1'));
        $('.mainpage__top--line-2').text(active.data('line-2'));
        $('.mainpage__top__description--line-1').text(active.data('description-line-1'));
        $('.mainpage__top__description--line-2').text(active.data('description-line-2'));
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
      });
      player.fadeIn('slow', function() {

        $('.mainpage__top').removeClass('changing');
        video.play();
      });
    });


  }
}
```

```css
.video_background {
  background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/header-bacground_opt.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 576px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
}

.video_background video {
  max-height: 576px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.mainpage__top {
  font-size: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  .video_background video {
    max-height: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .mainpage__top {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
  .mainpage__top__lines .mainpage__top--line-1 {
    width: 600px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 720px) {
  .mainpage__top {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
  .video_background {
    display: none;
  }
  .mainpage__top--line-1 {
    width: 450px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .mainpage__top {
    font-size: 4px;
  }
  .mainpage__top__line {
    font-size: 6.5em !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px 15px !important;
  }
  .mainpage__top__caption {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .mainpage__top--line-1 {
    width: 270px;
  }
  .video_background {
    display: none;
  }
}

.mainpage__top__line {
  font-weight: 300 !important;
}


}
.mainpage__top__caption,
.mainpage__top__line,
.mainpage__top__description {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.changing .mainpage__top__caption,
.changing .mainpage__top__line,
.changing .mainpage__top__description {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  opacity: .5;
}
.mainpage__top__caption::after,
.mainpage__top__line::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
.mainpage__top__caption {
  font-size: 3.6em;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  line-height: 1.04;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.mainpage__top__lines {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.mainpage__top__lines::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.mainpage__top__line {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 7em;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.mainpage__top--line-1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.mainpage__top--line-2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mainpage__top__description {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mainpage__top {
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mainpage__top {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videobg_pict">
  <div class="video_background js-video_background">
    <video class="video_background-player js-video_background-player" playsinline autoplay muted id="videobg" style=""></video>
    <ul class="js-video_background-playlist" style="display: none;">
      <li data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/header.mp4" data-caption="Разработка сайтов" data-line-1="Исправления ошибок" data-line-2="Все проверки через Validator" data-description-line-1="Работа со всеми странами." data-description-line-2="Общение на Украинском,Русском,Английском"></li>
      <li data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/header.mp4" data-caption="Оптимизация сайтов под Wordpress" data-line-1="Скорость отклика" data-line-2="Проверка с PageSpeed Insights" data-description-line-1="Работа со всеми странами." data-description-line-2="Общение на Украинском,Русском,Английском"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mainpage__top">
      <div><span class="mainpage__top__caption"></span></div>
      <div class="mainpage__top__lines">
        <div><span class="mainpage__top__line mainpage__top--line-1"></span></div>
        <div><span class="mainpage__top__line mainpage__top--line-2"></span></div>
      </div>
      <div><span class="mainpage__top__description mainpage__top__description--line-1"></span></div>
      <div><span class="mainpage__top__description mainpage__top__description--line-2"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А разметку мы сами должны угадать?

Comment: @Cheg прикрепил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно ты слышал, есть такая функция как setTimeout и даже есть setInterval. Обе функции выполняют callback по истечению заданного времени в мс, но с той лишь разницей что setTimeout выполняет функцию один раз, а setInterval бесконечно.

Каждые 5сек выводить в консоль запись:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Через 5 сек эта запись появится снова.");
}, 5 * 1000);
```